# NetPlan not applying static IP for VLAN

Tags: vlan, ubuntu-18.04

I setup a new `Ubuntu 18.04 server` and spend some time fighting with `netplan`. I only need a very simple network config, but for some reason it does not work and I have no idea what is wrong.

I need a `VLAN` with a `static IP`.

The problem: As soon as I configure any `static IP` (either on the physical interface or the `VLAN`) I loose any connection.

This is my current (not working) yaml (it is the only yaml, so there is no other config interfering)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: #the physical interface
    match:
      macaddress: "xx:xx:xx"
    dhcp4: no

    #this is the same IP I would get with dhcp
    addresses: [ "10.1.0.1/24" ]
    gateway4: 10.1.0.254
vlans:
  lab1:
    id: 10
    link: eth0
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [ "10.1.10.100/24" ]
```

After applying the config I got following IF<->IP:
eth0 <-> 10.1.0.1
lab1 <-> 10.1.0.1

And I was unable to connect to the server via `ssh` or `ping` it at this IP.

Configuration after running `netplan generate`:

10-netplan-eth0.network

```
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx

[Network]
Address=10.1.0.1/24
Gateway=10.1.0.254
VLAN=lab1
```

10-netplan-lab1.network

```
[Match]
Name=lab1

[Network]
Address=10.1.10.100/24
```

10-netplan-lab1.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=lab1
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=10
```

If I change both to `dhcp4: yes` and remove the addresses/gateway, I get the same addresses as statically configured above from `DHCP` and `ssh/ping` work for the `VLAN` address.

If I change `eth0` to `dhcp4: yes` and leave the static config for `lab1`, `lab1` gets a `DHCP` assigned address.

Why is the static address for `lab1` ignored?

Note: I was assured the switching/routing is correctly configured, but I am willing to check this again.

Comment: Could you run ```netplan generate``` and add the resulting configuration to your question? It will probably be in ```/run/systemd/network/```.

Comment: @KennyRasschaert Just added the configuration

Comment: Is cloud-init interfering with your configuration ? Do you have a `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg` or at least a `/etc/cloud` directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question may get other views, I thought I'd quickly answer.

The syntax of the YAML file must be correct in order for the items to be configured. Check the file with "netplan --debug generate" to see issues, else the generate and apply will configure whatever is valid, and ignore the rest (to be resilient - something is better than nothing).

In this case, the OP's indentation of the vlan section is incorrect. It must line up with the "ethernets" heading, indented from the "network" heading. Should be:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: #the physical interface
    match:
      macaddress: "xx:xx:xx"
    dhcp4: no

    #this is the same IP I would get with dhcp
    addresses: [ "10.1.0.1/24" ]
    gateway4: 10.1.0.254
  vlans:
    lab1:
      id: 10
      link: eth0
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [ "10.1.10.100/24" ]
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have the server anymore to test this, but this sounds reasonable. So I will accept this answer. netplan devs, if you read this, please make netplan print some sort of warning if the config files are malformed.